# How to avoid knockout bindings being called at page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel, which has a computed function called `updatePrices`. This method should never be called, unless a user toggle a checkbox inside my table.

The table is being generated by a `foreach` data-bind.

What I currently experience is the `updatePrices` method is being called for **every** row made in the table on page load, and then when the user toggle the checkbox. The behavior I expect, is it only calls the `updatePrices` when I toggle the checkbox, not on page-load.

So I basically want to avoid the methods being called on page-load. How do I do that?

**My html markup:**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: invoices">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: print, click:updatePrices()" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: invoiceDate"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: amount"></td>
        <td>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: pdfLink }">Download</a>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: status"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**My knockout function**:

```
self.updatePrices = ko.computed(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SingleLetter/GetPriceFromUrl',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            pdfUrl: self.pdfLink,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            self.jsonPrice(data.price);

        },
        error: function (file, responseText) {
            console.log('Price error');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I dont think you use computed function there. You are getting data from server upon user action. so when page loads or on user event g et data  from server ?

Comment: Maybe, I am very new to Knockout :) But I thought it was a computed function when I call it like that any my model has a ko.computed function?

Comment: When  you use computed function, whenever any observable in this computed changes your computed function gets computed. You should use computed function, when you need to make some calculation and transformation on an observable. Why you ever used computed function in first place?

Comment: Probably because I don't know Knockout very well, yet. But the same happens if I remove the ko.computed, and just use a function. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need to make updatePrices computable since it does not return any values, and does not rely on any other view model variables.

Second, your data binding for click is incorrect because you are immediately calling the function. Your data binding should look like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: print, click:updatePrices" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! Now my checkbox is broken, but that's probably some other bug ;) I'll go fetch. Thanks & good sunday!